# What investigatory procedures and decisions are there for a tourist death in Poland?

Tags: police, murder, poland

A friend of my girlfriend (from Ukraine) visited Poland. Unfortunately for him, he got killed. I do not know much further details. Parents claimed that it was due to external trauma (e.g. another guy or more beating him to death). What made me curious was the fact that the parents of the victim said, that there was neither an investigation, nor an autopsy in Poland. Instead they just got the ashes of their son back.

1. Is it possible in Poland that someone can be killed without an investigation?
2. Do you have to pay for autopsy in Poland?

Comment: I strongly suspect that the process is the same for anyone who is killed in Poland, among other reasons, because you can't always immediately determine the citizenship of a dead person. I also strongly suspect that someone had to do enough of an investigation to complete a death certificate  and ID a victim and that autopsies are done at state expense when necessary to complete a death certificate. But, I can't read Polish and don't have access to Polish legal sources, so I am not qualified to give a proper answer. Of course, it is possible for officials anywhere to be corrupt or incompetent.

Comment: And in complement to ohwilleke's comment, it is possible that your friend's fathers were just told that if they wanted to push the issue further than the police believed was needed (for example by asking for an autopsy of their son, or to hire a private investigator) it would be their private initiative and they would have to bear the costs. Of course, in case those initiatives provided some evidence of wrongdoing that should be passed to the police who would reopen the investigation.

Comment: @SJuan76 This could be possible. However, if someone got killed, isn't there always a need to continue the investigation?

Comment: As ohwilleke said, there is a minimum of investigation to issue the death certificate. But if the police has a certificate that says that the man died of an accident (e.g. he slipped and hit a rock with his head) or an internal medical condition, and there are no hints of anything else (his valuables were not missing, no reports of threats or fights, no witnesses claiming otherwise...) at some point the investigation just ends. Some people, even young people, die without being killed, and the police will not open a *criminal investigation* unless they at least suspect the possibility of crime.